# Trying to send get request with curl to hellosign API

Tags: php, curl

when I type into my browser: 'https://myemail:mypassword@api.hellosign.com/v3/account'

I get

```
{"account":{"account_id":"**************","email_address":"myemail","callback_url":null,"role_code":null}}
```

which appears to be a valid response.

I'm trying to implement this in php using the libcurl php library. I have the following, but get FALSE when I run var_dump on the $response variable. Any ideas on the settings for libcurl? I have tried urlencoding the entire string with and without base_64 encoding of the authentication substring 'myemail:mypassword. Thanks in advance:

```
$final_string= 'https://myemail:mypassword@api.hellosign.com/v3/account';    

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'HelloSign-PHP');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $final_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, self::$time_out); 

$response = curl_exec($curl);

    // Get the status code
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
        {
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
        }

curl_close($curl);


output is : 

Curl error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failedProblem connecting to HelloSign.
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you get no response? That `curl_exec()` returns `false`? What do you get from `curl_error()`? It should give you an indication of what went wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I went back and checked and there was actually a boolean - false being produced

Comment: Since the username and password are inline, you can actually use one of the socket functions. How about `echo file_get_contents('https://myemail:mypassword@api.hellosign.com/v3/account');`

Comment: Ok, so after `curl_exec()` you can call [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and see what it says about the failure.

Comment: please see changes above

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php

$api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
$url = 'https://api.hellosign.com/v3/account';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key . ":"); // Normally you'd put a password after the colon, but you don't need it if you're using an API key
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response_json = json_decode($response, true);

print_r($response_json);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Note: You don't need to use your API key (you can use your username and password, as commented above), but it's recommended. You can retrieve your API key here: https://www.hellosign.com/home/myAccount#api